# Using scc as code counter, how to ignore multiple adjacent subfolders and recursively other folders

Tags: bash, cloc

I am trying to use code counter software scc https://nicedoc.io/boyter/scc#user-content-sloc-cloc-and-code-scc

My folder is a typical Django project

```
--|
  |-- core (has subfolder: migrations)
  |-- app1 (has subfolder: migrations)
  |-- app2 (has subfolder: migrations)
  |-- static
  |-- staticfiles
```

The above is greatly simplified

I tried `scc -M static .`    which works great as it properly ignores the static folder

But I want to ignore both the static and staticfiles and also the migrations subfolders inside app1 and app2.

How do I do the above?

I don't quite understand the documentation inside the scc in order to pull this off.

Comment: it doesn't look like a Go issue. Did you try to create an issue in the project's repo?

Comment: looks like you can use multiple `-M` or you can give `-M` a regex - https://github.com/boyter/scc/issues/67

Comment: Thank you @jhnc eventually I worked it out based onw hat you found

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Thanks to @jhnc

```
scc --not-match="(static.*|migrations|.css|LICENSE|.gitignore|anyotherfoldername)" .
```